# How do I reference a bibliography in a path name with a -?

Tags: latex, biblatex

My work is all stored on our work's OneDrive and so the path name has a dash in it:

```
OneDrive - My Organization
```

I think I can handle the spaces, but the dash is giving me a problem. I can't get biblatex to find the file!
Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname - test.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname - test.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: filecontents does not produce the correct name for me, but once I renamed the bib file to `document -  test.bib` your document works fine for me

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: I renamed it via the file explorer of my operating system.

Comment: Alternatively `\begin{filecontents}{\jobname\space - test.bib}` works as well